# Salesforce CRM learning guide

Tags: learning, study-guide

I have enough exposure in force.com and now I want to learn Salesforce CRM.

How can I start on this?

Is there any guide available for this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I recommend Trailhead as the first resource for all help. Sign up using [trailhead.salesforce.com](https://trailhead.salesforce.com)

Apart from that Salesforce help and training portal has all the great info

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=salesforce_help_map.htm&language=en_US

Apart from this, Salesforce has implementation guides in both PDF and html formats.

You can refer these, they are excellent for hands on.

Comment: You can also create a free organization/account - that will also give you the time needed to have a real hands on. Creating objects of all types. And a developer account will allow you to add and implement coding into you org.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the excellent help and implementation guides @Mohith pointed out there is a lot of other online content.

The Salesforce online training has a selction of great online training courses.  You can see some of the trainings [directly on the help page (lower left corner)](https://help.salesforce.com/). The [Implementation Expert certification study guides](http://certification.salesforce.com/implementation-experts) list out the courses that are helpful for implementing Sales Cloud, and there are many, but your access to the various courses may depend on your relationship with Salesforce (partner, customer, etc.).

There are many very good Youtube sessions put out by Salesforce. You can find many linked to from:

- [Salesforce Youtube](http://www.youtube.com/user/salesforce)
- [Sales Cloud Youtube](http://www.youtube.com/user/SalesCloud)
- [Dreamforce Youtube](http://www.youtube.com/user/dreamforce)

The [Youtube demos by Alex Zarowny](http://www.youtube.com/user/alexzed?feature=watch) give quick (~15 mins), but thorough introductions to various areas of Salesforce from a user perspective.  They are a little bit older, but still relevant and very well done.  For example:

- [Getting Started With Content](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uAjiMc9KpCw&list=UUNcymONA2TJTSR9cBy27lhQ&index=10)
- [Products and Pricebooks in Salesforce](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kuYatMj-_4U&list=UUNcymONA2TJTSR9cBy27lhQ&index=14)
- [Campaigns in Salesforce](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FXVbFKRoZOM&list=UUNcymONA2TJTSR9cBy27lhQ)
- [Using Quotes in Salesforce](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CHT0vtd12BA&list=UUNcymONA2TJTSR9cBy27lhQ)

Answer (score 2):

I recommend [Trailhead](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/en). There you can find many modules, trails and even projects regarding Salesforce CRM. Trailhead is made by Salesforce and is my favorite learning platform.

My suggestion would be to start with [CRM essentials trail](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/en/trail/getting_started_crm_basics) and then proceed with [Admin Beginner](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/en/trail/force_com_admin_beginner), [Admin Intermediate](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/en/trail/force_com_admin_intermediate) and [Admin Advanced](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/en/trail/force_com_admin_advanced).

[Salesforce docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/) has many good guides. You can either download them as PDF or view online.