# As a tech person how to understand standard objects of out-of-box Salesforce?

Tags: standard-objects

By standard objects I mean *Accounts*, *Contacts*, *Contracts*, *Leads*, *Products*, *Solutions*, *blah blah blah*...

There are more than 30 of them come with Developer Edition (not sure about other editions). By their names I can understand most literally. But when they come together I don't know what to use and when to use... And how can one object turns to another under certain condition, etc.

I think this needs Sales Knowledge more or less. However is there any guideline or documents I can read about it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can take a look at the [ERDs for standard Salesforce objects](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/data_model.htm).  They are broken down into smaller, functional areas to make it easier to understand.

For example, here's the [Products and Schedules Objects ERD](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_erd_products.htm) which focuses in on Quotes, Opportunities, and Products:
[image]

For the purposes of learning how Salesforce CRM works, please see [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/9666/salesforce-crm-learning-guide).